# How is the freezing of water analyzed with the first law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

For the first law of thermodynamics ($\Delta E_{int} = Q + W$), it would seem that since $\Delta T = 0$, then the equation simplifies into $0=0+W$. However, since ice is less dense than water, volume expands ($\Delta V > 0$) as the freezing occurs, which seems to imply $W = -\int p dV < 0$.

Obviously, this is a contradiction so it cannot be correct, but where is the mistake?

Comment: Isothermal ($\Delta T=0$) doesn't imply adiabatic ($Q=0$). In addition, the internal energy generally depends on more than temperature (the ideal gas is an exception), so $\Delta T=0$ also doesn't generally imply $\Delta E=0$.

Comment: Following up on @Chemomechanics ' comment here; Change in $\triangle T = 0$ indeed does not mean  $\triangle E = 0$, as temperature is just the average measure of **translational kinetic energy** of the particles in the substance, $\therefore$ changing temperature does not necessarily mean there was no energy added or removed. There are other properties of material that can convert or store energy that do not relate to temperature.